# Git push complaining about non-fast-forward, even though remote has been pulled

Tags: git, dvcs, git-push

I'm trying to push my changes to a repo on my NAS.  It's failing in a way I don't understand.

The [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#_note_about_fast_forwards) states that by default `push` works only with fast-forward updates. Fair enough.  So I do a `git pull` (my remote is called `rubix`):

```
D:\RoboCup\Dev\TinMan>git pull rubix master
From ssh://rubix/volume1/git/TinMan
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

All looks well.  Let's try pushing...

```
D:\RoboCup\Dev\TinMan>git push rubix master
To ssh://dnoakes@rubix/volume1/git/TinMan
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://dnoakes@rubix/volume1/git/TinMan'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I've read through the documentation on `git push` but at this point I can't understand why I'm seeing this problem.

Here is some other contextual info:

```
D:\RoboCup\Dev\TinMan>git --version
git version 1.7.0.2.msysgit.0

D:\RoboCup\Dev\TinMan>git branch
* (no branch)
  master
```

That last line looks suspect.  How can I not be on any branch?  Note too that I have some untracked files and modifieds (unstaged) changes too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to get synced up.

First, Commit any changes, then use `git log` to note any commits you wanted to push.

Next reset your master to match the remote like this:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard remotes/rubix/master
```

Finally, cherry pick the commits you wanted to keep

Example:

```
git cherry-pick 111aaa111
git cherry-pick 123abc123
```

Now pushing should work.

```
git push rubix master
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you ended up on no branch. You may be in the middle of a rebase. You may have checked out a commit directly. In any event, this is likely the cause of your pushing woes. Check `git reflog` to see if it shows any obvious cause and `git log` to see where you are. Look at the changed files with `git diff` to decide if you want to keep them (and use `git add . && git stash` if you do). Then, once you are sure you don't need any changes or any of your current history, `git checkout master` to get back.

Comment: Thanks.  `git checkout master` makes sense, but I've now gone back in time.  Should I do `git merge <oldref>`?

Comment: Look through your `git reflog` to try to figure out where you were before. Assuming you know `<oldref>`, and that *it is a descendent of current master*, you can `git merge <oldref>`. Make sure that the output contains "Fast-forward". Otherwise, if you are creating a merge commit (for a non direct descendent), I would recommend creating a topical branch for those commits that has a useful name first.

Comment: Git printed out `<oldref>` when I checked out `master`.  Merging from that ref worked, and I was able to go ahead with what I was trying to do.  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If it still not work, you may probably need to configure your git to accept alias branch name

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

By default, if your remote branch name is **origin/master**, git will only accept your push if your local tracking branch name is **master**. If you create a local tracking branch as **master_xxx**, git will not accept your push unless you modify your **push.default** configuration to **upstream**.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and came across this question, so I thought I would post the solution to my problem.

NOTE: I am using git on Windows.

I had accidentally checked out my local branch with different casing: "Develop" instead of my usual "develop." Nothing I did would correct the issue (even after checking out the branch with the correct casing) until I followed these steps:

1. Checkout out the branch with the correct casing "develop"
2. Make any change, add/commit
3. Now you can push without being rejected